# Diagnostics.Trace across multiple domains

Tags: .net, logging, appdomain, trace

I didn't find information about how Trace and TraceListener work across multiple domains.

Does the calling of Trace.WriteLine use the same instance across multiple domains or it creates its own Trace class instance on each domain?

In other words..can i use Trace.Write in multi-threaded or multi-domain app and don't care about potential synch problems: races in writing to the same file from different domains e.t.c?

Comment: does multi-domain mean different exes or different asp.net sites (app pools)  in this context?

Comment: no. many domains in one exe file. not asp.net context

Comment: what kind of TraceListener are you adding?

Comment: TextWriterTraceListener and out stream is file stream and later i am going to write own listeners (ConsoleFormListener e t c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-appDomain access to Console.Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548364/cross-appdomain-access-to-console-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each appDomain uses own instance of static class therefore i am can't use Trace.Write across multiple domains.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this nice post which may suggest a way forward:

http://philsversion.com/2009/05/14/how-to-use-debugwrite-and-tracewrite-across-app-domain-boundries/

All credit to the original author.